# how to tell css what to do if javascript is not present

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I really like fall backs. I hardly ever use javascript or jquery, but when i do I like to provide a fallback. You can't even navigate on some sites today without javascript being present in your browser. Some developers take it so for granted that if it isn't present you can't navigate or access content. Even the Twitter Bootstrap doesn't provide a fall-back. If javascript is disabled the mobile menu will not display or expand.

I am using jquery's .toggle function to display and hide my mobile menu. I have my menu's container set as **display: none;** in my css so that the menu is hidden when you first visit my site. I want to have it so if javascript is disabled or not present in the browser the menu container is simply displayed.

I realize that 99% of the time js will most likely be present and enabled. I would still like to do this. So here is my code.

html / js

```
    <header>
    <div id="click">Toggle</div>
</header>

<div id="mobilemenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Random</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submit</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

<script>
    var flip = 0;
    $("#click").click(function () {
    $("#mobilemenu").toggle();
    });
</script>
```

css

```
    /* header */
header {
    background: #2e97de;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: #287eb9 1px solid;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
    display: block;
}

/* mobile menu */
#mobilemenu {
    border-top: #8dc8f2 1px solid;
    min-width: 100%;
    background: #2e97de;
    display: none;
}

#mobilemenu ul {

}

#mobilemenu li {
    display: block;
}

#mobilemenu li a {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #95d3ff;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

As you can see my menu is simple an unordered list with three list-items inside of a div. What I would like to do is allow the div **#mobilemenu** to be visible if js isn't enabled or present. But if js is enabled or present I'd like #mobilemenu to not be displayed.

I would also appreciate any feed back that tells me how to beef up my jquery that handles the toggle.

Comment: Can you make #mobilemenu visible by default, but hide it with JavaScript when the page loads?

Answer (score 2):

I would keep is visible and then hide it with jQuery

```
$("#mobilemenu").css("display","none");
```

This way it is only hidden if Javascript is enabled

Comment: Okay, I put it at the very bottom right before </body> and it works. Why does it have to be at the very bottom? Not a problem just curious.

Comment: it could be `on dom ready` otherwise it shouldn't matter unless it's getting overwritten by your CSS if it's placed above it.

Comment: My css shouldn't be overwriting it. It's te same as above minus the display none. I don't follow you `on dom ready`

Comment: After reading it looks like I need `$(document).ready` when not placing js at the bottom. Not to savvy in js. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If this answer helped, could you mark it as correct to help other users, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

remove the display property in mobilemenu style definition and hide it with javascript.

```
$('#mobilemenu').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more declarative approach, I would suggest having a CSS class that add you to the body tag that indicates that JS is available.  You can then use that class to style any parts of the page differently if JS is or isn't present.

```
<style>
#mobilemenu { display: none }
.withjs #mobilemenu {
    display: block;
}
</style>

<body class="nojs">
...
<script>
$('body').removeClass('nojs').addClass('withjs')
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have two style sheets. Load them accordingly:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jsdisabled.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="jsenabled.css" />');
</script>
```